# Jenkins Email notification sent successfully but not delivered

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext, jenkins-mailer-plugin

Below is the log and its working fine when i ask Jenkins to send it to individuals but the same is not working fine when i ask Jenkins to send it to a distribution list.

`04:22:08 Email was triggered for: Always
04:22:08 Sending email for trigger: Always
04:22:08 Request made to compress build log
04:22:08 Sending email to: XXXXXX.XXX@XXXX.com
04:22:08 Finished: UNSTABLE`

any help?

Answer (score 1):

enable the  option Extended E-mail Notification -> Allow sending to unregistered users  and try again.

If Still not receiving the emails, enable the  option Extended E-mail Notification -> Enable Debug Mode. So that you will get detailed message.

Answer (score 0):

That usually means you are using an exchange server and the distribution group has only allow authenticated users (which is the default)

Comment: Sorry am bit confused here, do i need to add each individuals separately? or you are saying Jenkins should send mails even for distribution group ?

Comment: I’m saying the email server is discarding the email because it’s not from an authenticated source. Either you get the mail server updated, enter login details in mail settings or use individual addresses